# Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$amnt_paid

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I don't know how to resolve this, I've read similar questions about this but I can't find a solution. I'm a beginner to php.

> Error: Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$amnt_paid

```
<?php
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amnt_paid) FROM payment WHERE dr_no=546 AND paymnt_desc='Monthly Installment'")->row()->amnt_paid;
    echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: If you're new, a good practise is to make the code clear. Also, you should quotate the string `amnt_paid` to be like `'amnt_paid'`

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an alias for result of a `SUM` and refer to it:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT SUM(amnt_paid) as total 
    FROM payment 
    WHERE dr_no=546 AND paymnt_desc='Monthly Installment'")
   ->row()->total;
```

And in your current query you don't select `amnt_paid` field, you select field that is named `SUM(amnt_paid)`. Somehow, this property can be accessed too, something like:

```
->row()->{'SUM(amnt_paid)'};
```

but it is better to use an alias.